# How to make an horizontal box-and-whiskers plot in gnuplot

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, boxplot, candlestick-chart

How do you make an horizontal box-and-whiskers plot in gnuplot? Similarly to this one:

[image: an horizontal box-and-whiskers plot]

Gnuplot can easily be used to produce vertical box-and-whiskers plots with the 'candlesticks' and 'whiskerbars' keywords, but I have not managed to find any example of an horizontal candlesticks/box-and-whiskers horizontal plot produced via gnuplot online.

Example of a vertical plot produced by gnuplot:

[example of a vertical box-and-whiskers plot http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~dts/cop3530/proj02/candlesticks.6.png](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~dts/cop3530/proj02/candlesticks.6.png)

Comment: If you have to have this layout, as an alternative, I"m pretty sure you can do the horizontal box-and-whiskers in Excel, but it is a multi-step, error prone process. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot generally doesn't switch directions well... for example you can't plot rows instead of columns, and it's hard to make histograms (or any other kind of plot) go horizontal instead of vertical.

People have made horizontal histograms, however, and you might be able to modify the code found **[at this site](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/10/turning-of-histogram.html)**.

Comment: Clever! To summarise the site linked: do a vertical plot, and rotate everything 90 degrees.