# Plotting word frequency histogram using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to plot the histogram of the following data file.

```
data.txt
=========
countries       1
domestic        1
fourth-largest  3
in      4
airline 5
and     8
destinations    3
```

I want to plot the histogram of word frequency(y axis) against the word(x axis).

Comment: To make a horizontal histogram, you can also see my answer to [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823873/how-to-make-an-horizontal-box-and-whiskers-plot-in-gnuplot/

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror rotate by -90 offset character 0, 0, 0
plot "data.txt" using 2:xticlabels(1) with histogram
```